# 2 bootstrap navbars one fixed to top and one to bottom won't accept different colours

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap navbar static to the top and one static on the bottom
I want the background colour of the bottom one to be a radial gradient (which I have done and colour i will customize) but then the background-color of the top navbar changes as well I tried using "#" to select the element but that wouldn't work either.
Here's the html:

```css
.navbar-header .navbar-brand:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
  color:lightblue;
  list-style-type:none;
}
.navbar-custom /*bottom navbar music player.*/ {
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, red, blue);
    color:#ffffff;
    border-radius:0;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container-fluid">
        
<div class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" id="main-navbar" >
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header"> 
        <a href="" class="navbar-brand">FaceTheMusic</a>

            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse" aria-expanded="false">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="">Home</a> </li>
                <li><a href="">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Search</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Upload</a></li>
            </ul>
         <form action="" class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
 <div class="form-group">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search here" />
 </div>
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
 </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
        </div>


<div id="navPlayer" class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-bottom">
    
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
   
</button>

</div>
```

I think only the css on the top is relevant but have inserted the whole styleseheet just in case.

Kind regards,

Comment: What color is the top meant to be?

Comment: A lightblue for the top navbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using `.navbar-custom` which is applied to both navbars.

```
.navbar-fixed-top{
    /*css for top nav*/
}
.navbar-fixed-bottom{
    /*css for bottom nav*/
}
```